# Techniques for plotting PCA projections in more than three dimensions

Tags: data-visualization, pca, dimensionality-reduction, scatterplot

After running PCA on my data set, I noticed that using the three first eigenvectors, a separation between two different classes is still achievable (doing PCA on data from two classes). Unfortunately, it doesn't scale up very well and when I feed in data from 15 different classes, I get a big blob of dots when I plot the reprojected data in three dimensions. I want to find out if those classes are actually separated in higher dimensions. Is there techniques used to visualize scatter plots of data in more than 3 dimensions?

I have read about using different [shapes](http://informationandvisualization.de/blog/5dimensional-scatter-plot) (dots, triangles, squares, and their respective area) to fit more information in a 3D scatter plot but how would you code that relative to the values delivered by PCA?

Comment: First, you can plot all possible 2d scatterplots ("scatterplot matrix"), like e.g. in this answer http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101490. Second, you can try to use a supervised method such as LDA, see here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161362.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comments by amoeba:

> First, you can plot all possible 2d scatterplots ("scatterplot
> matrix"), like e.g. in this answer [stats.stackexchange.com/a/101490](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/101490).
> Second, you can try to use a supervised method such as LDA, see here
> [stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161362](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161362).